# Mongoose: atomic find and update in nested document array, conditionally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an Express route `OfferRouter.route('/:offerId/series/:seriesId')` to access the following nested Mongoose document:

```
var Series = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ...
    active: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    qty: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

var Offer = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ... 
    series : [
        { type: Series }
    ]
});
```

I need to find the specific seriedId inside the offerId document, then check if it's `active` & if `qty > 0`, and only then decrement `qty`. 
Otherwise, I'll have to return errors for the `active == false` or `qty == 0` situations.

I thought about chaining those sequential steps, but then it wouldn't be atomic, right?
**How do I do this atomically, with Mongoose?**

It would also be nice to project out only the series document.

I was trying something like this, but I don't know how to check active and qty; nor how to project out only the series document found; and I don't know hot to get the specific errors either:

```
    Offers.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: offerId, 
        series._id: seriesId
    }, {
        $dec: { "series.$.qty" : 1 } 
    }, function(err, series) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        ...
        res.json(...);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [array filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) for that like so:

```
var query = { _id: offerId };
var update = { $inc: { 'series.$[elem].qty': -1 } };
var options = {
    arrayFilters: [ { 'elem._id': seriesId, 'elem.active' : true, 'elem.qty': { $gt: 0 } } ],
    projection: { _id: 0, series: 1 } // return only the "series" field
};
Offers.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, ...);
```

Comment: I was able to do it by using  {_id:offerId, series:  {$elemeMatch: { _id: seriesId, active:true, qty: {$gt:0} }}} in the query criteria, but your solutions works too. Thank you.

Comment: If you do it using the solution you described, you will end up updating only one element (the first matching one). The solution I suggested will update all found elements.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. In my case it's a findOneAndUpdate, so it's just one element actually. But your solution might serve someone else's needs too, that's why I'm accepting.

Comment: It's about the number of items **inside** the array not the number of documents that are getting updated. Your code will only update the first item inside the array for the single document found that your looking for. If, however, you wanted to update all matching items inside the array in the found document you'd need to go with the solution above.